# paste() on a vector gives unwanted whitespace, how to remove it?

Tags: r, newline, whitespace, paste

I am trying to remove whitespace from objects in a vector in R. I have problems when I use the function `paste`; it gives me the objects of `a` with a `space`.

```
a <- c(1985, 1986, 2004)
i <- 0
while(i<(length(a))) {
  i <- i+1
  b <- (paste("C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/",
      a[[i]]))
  c <- paste(b,"/Invierno/band3.tif")
  (paste(a[[i]],"3")) <- raster(c)
}
c
```

And the result of c is

> "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/
>   1985 /Invierno/band3.tif"

instead of:

> "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes
>   Landsat/1985/Invierno/band3.tif"

(The problem is in the year 1985)

Comment: eventually you can use `paste0()`

Comment: Alteratively, use `paste0` instead of `paste` which is basically the same as @CarlesSansFuentes suggests.

Comment: use the parameter `sep=""` in `paste`

Comment: as a side note you can have an easier time using `file.path` when constructing file paths like that. saves you from thinking about `/`s

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about what your the last step is doing `raster(c)`, but I'd suggest to skip the while loop and use paste0 as said in the comments:

```
paste0("C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/",
       c(1985, 1986, 2004),
       "/Invierno/band3.tif")
# "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/1985/Invierno/band3.tif"
# "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/1986/Invierno/band3.tif"
# "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/2004/Invierno/band3.tif"
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to set the 'sep' argument in paste function to  ""
this is basically to set the separators between the objects you are pasting togather.
default separator is a white-space, so you need to override that.

```
a <- c(1985, 1986, 2004)
i <- 0
while(i<(length(a)))
{
  i <- i+1
  b <- paste("C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/", a[[i]] , sep = '')
  c <- paste(b,"/Invierno/band3.tif", sep='')
  (paste(a[[i]],"3")) <- raster(c)
}
c
```

This would result in

"C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/1985/Invierno/band3.tif"

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c(1985, 1986, 2004)

#You can use paste0:
paste0("C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/", a, "/Invierno/band3.tif")
#[1] "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/1985/Invierno/band3.tif"
#[2] "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/1986/Invierno/band3.tif"
#[3] "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/2004/Invierno/band3.tif"

#or paste:
paste("C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/", a, "/Invierno/band3.tif", sep = "")
#[1] "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/1985/Invierno/band3.tif"
#[2] "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/1986/Invierno/band3.tif"
#[3] "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Fran/Tesis/Sin sincronizar/Imagenes Landsat/2004/Invierno/band3.tif"
```

By default, `paste` separate the parts by a space.